# how to resolve import/no-unresolved with setup of eslint in webpack 4

Tags: javascript, webpack, eslint, webpack-4, eslintrc

I have researched for a few hours. build a prototype myself and found that the webpack is working on its resolving alias but eslint kept reporting unable to resolve, EVEN after I jammed in setting supposedly resolve this issue.

Anyone know why adding

```
"settings": {
        "import/resolver": {
            "alias": [
        [ "mycomponents", "./app/components" ]
      ]
        }
    }
```

to .eslintrc
and add two packages related to it won't do it?

to see what I did check this repo diff link: https://github.com/KleoPetroff/react-webpack-boilerplate/compare/master...adamchenwei:master

Note: i could have just hide the eslint error, but that's just a hack route which I would rather not to take, if there is a proper setup.

Thanks

Answer (score 23):

Try adding [eslint-import-resolver-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-import-resolver-alias) to your project:

```
npm i eslint-import-resolver-alias --save-dev
```

Then update your `.eslintrc` file as follows:

```
"settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
        "alias": {
            map: [
                [ "mycomponents", "./app/components" ]
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not working for me not sure why :(

Comment: @Pants, it happened to me before I add extensions, try to add extensions below the map, i.e. `"extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".json"]`

Comment: Another thing to note is that the `map` key expects an array of arrays.

I didn't notice that before, so, using this example, I had: `"map": [ "mycomponents", "./app/components" ]`, which is an array of strings, versus:
`"map": [[ "mycomponents", "./app/components" ]]`, which is an array of arrays